# What is the HTTP referrer for Firefox when opening a link in a new tab?

Tags: firefox, http-referrer

Just out of curiosity:

My default browsing behavior (with FireFox 3.5) is to open links in a new tab.  If I am searching something in google, I always right-click search results and open them in a new tab.  If I am looking at popular links on delicious.com, I right-click and open the link in a new tab.

So I am wondering what the HTTP Referrer would show for my visits when I land on a site.  **If I "follow" a link from delicious by right-click & opening in a new tab, does FireFox tell the site that I came there from delicious, or does it treat it like I opened a new tab and typed the URL in myself?**

I don't have any web servers that I can see the referrer for, otherwise I would test this out myself.

Thanks!

Comment: A Google-Search Tip, maybe not new, and most certainly not an answer to your question ... : Did you know, that when you click on preferences next to the search button, then scroll down, there is a radio-control labeled "Open search results in a new browser window."

Comment: Very interesting!  I wasn't aware of that option - I just turned it on, which should save me a bit of clicking around :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In FF 3.0.11 it sends the referrer exactly as if you had opened it in the same window (tells the site where you came from).  As far as I know this behavior is true for all browsers.

The FF [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) addon is good for testing these kinds of things.

Comment: Yep - you are right!  I setup the Live HTTP Headers addon and then right clicked & opened in a new tab your link to the addon, and the referrer showed up as superuser.com.

Thanks very much for the answer, and the reference to a great addon!

Comment: FF and IE send the referral header. Chrome and Safari do not.